# Replace a list of words in word for translating

Tags: ms-word

I have two list of words in language A
noun list A = [noun_1_A][noun_2_A]...[noun_m_A]
verb list A = [verb_1_A][verb_2_A]...[verb_n_A]
and two corresponding lists in language B
noun list B = [noun_1_B][noun_2_B]...[noun_m_B]
verb list B = [verb_1_B][verb_2_B]...[verb_n_B]

Only when a noun in the noun list stay before a verb in the verb list in language A then both of them will be translated following the corresponding word in language B. Otherwise the noun will be translated into something else.

My question is is that possible to use the word search and replace wildcard to do this task. VBA or other programming language is not favored because of the font issue. Many thanks.

Comment: Your problem description is not clear - perhaps if you provide some examples it would be clearer... Please read the information on asking questions in the StackOverflow Help Center -  http://stackoverflow.com/help.

Comment: Sorry I will try to make it more clear. Given a paragraph in language A, word should find all the pair that has the pattern {noun verb}, which is a noun in the noun list follow by a verb in the verb list. It then replace this with the corresponding pair in language B. I can do that by make it replace all the possible combination between the two list, but that will be a lot of work. So I wonder if word wildcard can do. I know it can do in case the noun list and verb list in language B is just a single word... Thanks.

Comment: The question is still not clear - and it would be better for you to add any examples and details to the original question. HOWEVER, as best I understand your requirement Find/Replace without VBA cannot do this for the simple reason that it has no access to your lists. You would still have to type the Find/Replace combinations into the dialog box.

Comment: You should also add information by editing the original question about the "font issue". What font issue? And again, I urge you to read the information on asking questions in the Help center.

Comment: The language is in Unicode so if using VBA I need to know the ASCII character (I have tried with macro recorded), and for other programming language it either had problem with input reading or ouput writing.

Comment: Here is a simple example. Noun list = {I you we}. Verb list = {go run}. In language B, there is a special meaning for the word in this list when they sit together, for example, Noun list in B = {N1 N2 N3}, Verb list in B = {V1 V2}. In the paragraph if there are any "I go" "we run" or something like that it will need to be replaced by "N1 V1" "N3 V2"... The real stuff I can't post also because of the font issue. Thanks.

Comment: PLEASE click the "Edit" link under your original question and add ALL this information to the Question. But I repeat that you can't solve this without some code in the mix...